# how to protect and clean ISP-library from malicious eval adds

Tags: php, malware

in a older directory of my ISP i've found many eval code adds, that do not obviously affect the function but it seems to open a trojan-connection.

code is:

```
eval(base64_decode("ZXJyb3Jf ..... this is malware  ..... BleGl0KCk7IH0gfSB9IH0gfSB9IH0="));
```

+

i decoded this cod on  http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/
however, it may be a risk to publish the result here ... I suppose the code enable "http://plkierng.rebatesrule.net" -- the spamer -- to do his job using my web.
my questions:
1. how can i clean the drive on my ISP-server?
2. how can i prevent this problem in future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can answer this definitively. If you simply delete the eval code (or files containing it) you will stop it being callable, however if the flaw used to upload the files still exists your system will be reinfected. There is also no guarantee that other files which don't have eval statements are not backdoors/malware.

The correct way is to delete everything and start again if you don't know exactly what was affected and how.  If you are willing to take the risk, you might be able to get away with using AV software to scan for malware, delete it and make sure everything is running current software and new passwords.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you might also be able to mitigate your risk by adding an open_basedir directive to your virtualhosts which limits where PHP can read files, and also setting disable_function in your php.ini to disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority